# How do I get access to values of object inside nested objects?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I am trying to have a nested object with a structure similar to this one:

[EDIT] - Updated the object to better explain the situation

```
const theme = {
  primary: "#18f4c9",
  secondary: "#3264E8",
  background: "#1E3359",
  none: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
  buttons: {
     borders: {
       primary: `none`,
       secondary: `1px solid ${theme.primary}`
     },
     background: {
       primary: `${theme.primary}`,
       secondary: `${theme.none}`
     },
     text: {
       primary: "#000",
       secondary: `${theme.primary}`
     }
  }
};
```

I get why I have this error now. I'm trying to use this in react for specific components. And when I init the object later I don't get the specifications I needed.

I get this error message:

> Cannot access 'objectTest' before initialization

I don't know if this is even possible without hard coding it. But I have a much larger object but want to access these values several levels deep. Is this even possible?

Comment: No, not possible. The error explains why. The object doesn't exist before the initialization, so JS doesn't know what `objectTest.greeting` is. To avoid duplicate strings, just init the object, then do `objectText.valueToGet = \`${objectTest.greeting}\`;` in the next line.

Comment: @ChrisG I just updated the question with more information on the object I'm working. This is for a theme provider in React. I understand I have to init the object , but for some reason it doesnt get the data when I reproduce the component.

Comment: What do you mean by "reproduce the component"? Can you create a [mre]?

Comment: @ChrisG
Does this work?

BUTTON COMPONENT:
const Button = styled.button`
 ${props =>
    props.type &&
    `
      background-color: ${props => props.theme.test[props.type]}
    `}
`;
`

THEME
const theme = {
  primary: 'hi',
}
theme.test = {1: `${theme.primary}. 2: null`}

I created a theme like in the docs and nested everything inside it.

So when I render the components its just like this:
<Button type={1}>...</Button>

Dont know if its minimal enough, first time asking a question on StackOverflow. Thanks!